# g++ compiles array with size given at runtime by const value (not constexpr)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Can someone clarify why is this legal C++ code? (Yes, I'm asking why my code works ;) )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t N = 10; 

    int a[N]{}; // value-initialize it to get rid of annoying un-initialized warnings in the following line
    std::cout << a[5] << std::endl; // got a zero 
}
```

The size of the array is declared as `const` (NOT `constexpr`), still the program compiles with no warnings (`-Wall`, `-Wextra`, `-Wpedantic`) in both g++ and clang++. I thought that the C++ standard explicitly specified that the size of the array should be a compile-time constant. It is absolutely not the case here.

Comment: A `const` integral type can be used in a context where a *constant expression* is required. This feature was already in C++98. (Not sure about the combination `const volatile` though.)

Comment: I think a better question would be *can a const volatile integral be a constant expression*?

Comment: @RyanHaining I actually made a small mistake, now realized that the `const volatile` spits a warning in `g++` actually. Re-edited the question. Just consider the `const` version, both `g++` and `clang++` compile it with no warnings.

Comment: @MattMcNabb removed the comment. I still don't get why then one cannot use `const` instead of `constexpr` e.g. in template meta - programming. From the answers I get, it looks like `const` behaves similarly, and that's not the case. I don't remember where exactly I've read about `const`, but it was explicitly mentioned that the initialization may be done at runtime. Then how can it be a compile-time constant? Is then the only difference between `constexpr` and `const` the fact that `constexpr` is forced to be computed (if possible) at compile-time, whereas `const` can be deferred to run-time?

Comment: @vsoftco: It is a compile time constant when it is initialized with a compile time constant, and the initialization happens at compile time in that case. When it is not initialized with a compile-time constant, it is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that's exactly what I thought about `constexpr`. Are you talking about `constexpr` or `const`?

Comment: I'm talking about `const`. Don't ask me about `constexpr` though, I haven't used it much, and must admit ignorance of its nuances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

N4140 §5.19 [expr.const]/p2, bullet 2.7.1, and p3:

> 2 A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the
>   evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization,
>       initialized with a constant expression [ *Note*: a string literal
>       (2.14.5) corresponds to an array of such objects. —*end note* ]
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`, or that refers to a non-mutable sub-object of such an object, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began
>       within the evaluation of `e`;
> - [...]
>
> 3 An *integral constant expression* is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression. [ *Note*: Such expressions may be used as array bounds (8.3.4, 5.3.4), as bit-field lengths (9.6), as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is not fixed (7.2), and as alignments (7.6.2). —*end note* ]

In your code, `N` is a "non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type", it refers to a "non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization", so applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to it does not prevent the expression from being a core constant expression despite the absence of `constexpr`.

Comment: I found this to be extremely confusing (even though it is the standard), and somehow making `constexpr` obsolete

Comment: @vsoftco How does this make `constexpr` obsolete? It's a special exception for `const` integer types (and unscoped enums). `constexpr` allows you to do much, much more.

Comment: obsolete is a harsh term probably, but in my opinion  `arr[const]` shouldn't be allowed, as it is explicitly mentioned that the `const` is NOT a compile-time constant. I now realized that the standard considers it as a const-time expression in this case, but then my question is why use `constexpr`? why not just make `const` have the role of `constexpr` (whenever this is possible)?

Comment: @vsoftco : This behavior (re: `const`) has been around since before ISO standardization in 1998; `constexpr` is new to C++11. Removing this behavior now would be absolutely backwards-incompatible - how is this contentious?

Answer (score 6):

Where did you get that strange idea that `N` is "absolutely NOT a compile-time constant", as you state in the code comments?

Since the beginning of times, a `const` integral object declared with an *integral constant expression* initializer by itself forms an *integral constant expression*. I.e. is a *compile-time constant* in C++.

This applies equally to namespace declarations, local declarations and static class member declarations.

(It would not be a compile-time constant in C. But it has always been a compile-time constant in C++.)

Comment: maybe I don't understand `constexpr` then, I now see absolutely no reason for using the new `constexpr` keyword to do the `enum` trick in meta-programming.

Answer (score 1):

Well - N is constant during compilation so it is equivalent to

int a[10]{};

Comment: `const` is not the same as `constexpr`, a `const` may be initialized at runtime, and not at compile time. See the reason for the new `constexpr` keyword.

Comment: @vsoftco: A const which is initialized by a constant expression is a constant expression.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That depends on the type. You can write `const double d = 0;`, which is initialized by a constant expression, but `d` may not itself be used in a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

A const int initialized with a literal is considered a constant expression

From [N1905 5.19](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)

> An integral constant-expression can involve only literals of arithmetic types  enumerators, non-volatile **const** variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types **initialized with constant expressions**

Note the "non-volatile," indicating your original code should have been rejected by g++.

Comment: N1905? Why N1905 from 2005?

Comment: @dyp I was just looking for something prec++11 to show this isn't new behavior.  T.C. seems to have found the relevant recent standard quote, so I won't bother hunting it down in other standards.

Comment: I've looked in the C++03 Standard, and I think the part about `volatile` is missing there. Strange (= probably a defect). Edit: Yes, here it is: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#457

Comment: @dyp Hm, so g++ is behaving acceptably under C++03 (though unsafely) but breaking the standard in C++11.

Comment: @Ryan The document number is orthogonal to how old it is (bigger document number doesn't necessarily mean newer.) It also doesn't say anything about the state of compiler conformance, unless the documentation explicitly says that it's using that document as a basis.

Comment: @remyabel right but it says 2005, which I figured would be close enough to 03 with touchups